# Find the difference of rows within a column

Tags: sql, difference

[I want to create a new table where the difference of weight will be displayed as
weight diff. for eg first day the difference is 0, so second day for the same id the weight should be like +.. for gain and - .. for loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFeSq.png)

Comment: Your image is unreadable, one reason by sample data should be presented as *text* tables.  Similarly, your question should show the results you want and have a tag for the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (weight -
        lag(weight, 1, weight) over (partition by id order by date)
       ) as weight_diff
from t;
```

Your image is really hard to read so I just used the names given in the description.

Comment: thank you, it worked. Also, can you help me how to find difference between first and last id(same id) of a row.

Comment: @neerajrokaya . . . I don't know what you mean by "first and last id of a row".  A row has only one id.  Sample data and desired results would help (in a new question).